# Не понимаю как создать матрицу в латехе

Tags: latex, texstudio

Все делаю по гайду, но все равно вылезает ошибка

[image]

Пробовал менять символы, двигать табуляцию, менять окружение

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/#12120) Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [edit])

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проблема связана с тем, что среда `pmatrix` неопределенна в стандартном LaTeX.
Вам нужно добавить `\usepackage{amsmath}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
  $
  \begin{pmatrix}
    a & b \\
    c & d \\
  \end{pmatrix}
  $
\end{document}
```